# SQL Server Bulk Import - can't get it working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert, bulk

DTSX package isn't working properly any longer (credentials), so looking at bulk insert in T-SQL, but can't seem to get it working.

Any ideas? Sample information below:

```
"PropertyNumber"|"CardNumber"|"BuildingFeatureTypeCode"|"DwellingFeatureTypeCode"|"Area"|"Depreciation"|"AllocatedValue"|"AllocatedVP"|"FeatureValue"|"OverrideSwitch"|"Rate"
"99-999959"|"001"|""|"ALC"|1.00000|.00000|.00000|.00000|8500.00000|.00000|8500.00000
"99-999959"|"001"|""|"W/S"|1.00000|.00000|.00000|.00000|.00000|.00000|.00000
"99-999199"|"001"|""|"W/S"|1.00000|.00000|.00000|.00000|.00000|.00000|.00000
"99-999299"|"001"|""|"W/S"|1.00000|.00000|.00000|.00000|.00000|.00000|.00000
"99-999259"|"001"|""|"W/S"|1.00000|.00000|.00000|.00000|.00000|.00000|.00000
```

Comment: We can't guess the solution.  Please share some code and an error.

Answer (score 0):

[Bulk Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is also working for SQL server 2008. Here is an example:

```
BULK INSERT Sales.Orders
FROM '\\SystemX\DiskZ\Sales\data\orders.dat';
```